# Не найден модуль libtorrent

Tags: python, импорт, модули

Я установил libtorrent используя

```
pip install lbry-libtorrent
```

но при попытке `import libtorrent as lt` появляется ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
```

Comment: У вас несколько питонов в разных окружениях. Вы поставили библиотеку в один питон, а запускаете другой.

Comment: @CrazyElf не факт. Там библиотека какой то странный бинд на С++ либу без какой либо вообще внятной документации. Возможно, просто не то импортирует.

Comment: Вообщем по задумке автора сего творения оно как то не так просто работает. Не по питоняче http://libtorrent.org/python_binding.html

Comment: Вряд-ли проблема в версии питона. Я устанавливал библиотеки для этого проекта таким-же способом и запускал так-же как и другие файлы из этого проекта.